# Laravel 8 - Multi Auth with two diffirent registration form?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm using laravel breeze as auth scaffolding package I want to know How can I
create two diffirent registration form for two User Types here is a simple explanation of hwat I want to achieve:

**resources/auth/developer :**

*developer-register.blade.php*

**resources/auth/designer :**

*designer-register.blade.php*

if the Visitor choose to register as "developer" it will display a diffirent form. and same thing for if the Visitor choose to register as "designer" it will display a diffirent form with fields.

I wish you understand what I want to achieve with this easy explanation.

Comment: Are you treating both of these registrations as instances of a single `User` class? Or will you have a `Designer` and `Developer` class which are authenticatable?

Comment: **Designer** and **Developer** Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i've not used `laravel/breeze` myself (yet) but it shouldn't be much different from doing it in standard Laravel!

---

#### Views

By default, it looks like the `breeze` scaffolding is going to hit a `create()` method on the `RegisteredUserController` which will return a single view like so:

`RegisteredUserController.php`

```
    /**
     * Display the registration view.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }
```

You have a few options here:

1. Replace this view with another
2. Add some logic to change the view which is returned based on the request being made (you can inject a `Request` object into the route like any other)

```
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->has('developer')) {
            return view('auth.developer-register');
        } else {
            return view('auth.designer-register');
        }
    }
```

3. Keep the original `auth.register` view and handle the logic in the blade template.

---

#### Registration

The forms on each of your registration pages will have an action that points to a controller route. This will likely be the `RegisteredUserController` within which you will find a `store()` method that handles the creation of a `User` model.

---

`RegisteredUserController.php`

```
    /**
     * Handle an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:8',
        ]);

        Auth::login($user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]));

        event(new Registered($user));

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
    }
```

---

As you can see, this `store()` method is handling the creation of a `User` model and then authenticating it before redirecting the user to the `home` route.

What you could do, is check the request for the the requested user type and then use a switch statement to change the type of use being created.

```
switch ($request->get('user_type'))
    case 'developer':
        $user = Developer::create([ /* add details here */ ]);
        break;
    case 'designer':
        $user = Designer::create([ /* add details here */ ]);
        break;

Auth::login($user);
```

---

I hope this will at least inspire you with your own solution!